# how do we create our own 64 bit integer from sint and uint

Tags: integer

How can we create our user defined 64-bit integer from the two given 32 bit integer sint and uint.

Please help me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) If you want us to help you, show that you've put some effort into it.

Comment: Do you want the resulting 64-bit number to be the sum/difference of the two inputs? Product/quotient/remainder/modulus? Sign-extended widening? One input in the top half and the other in the bottom? If so, which one goes where?

Comment: i was thinking as defining a structure with two members with sint being the 1st member and uint being the 2nd and typedef the structure as Integer64.And i expect a variable can be defined like Integer64 var1 like the normal compilers support for declaring int a etc. So when a no. is received i would shift the 1st 32 bit to uint and the rest to sint. But how can i do this is the problem. I want to know how the comiplers declare declares  the memory when we say int x;double y.